# What counts as "signing in" for Windows Live Mail's 365-day requirement?

Tags: outlook.com

Whenever you set up Windows Live Mail (Hotmail) to forward emails from one account to another, you get the following message:

> Important note: Please sign in at least once every 365 days—otherwise your account looks inactive and could be deleted.

By logging in, do you have to literally go to http://mail.live.com, or has anyone successfully kept the account alive only sending/receiving messages via POP3 or IMAP and a third party client?